# How to Retrieve Values only from Nodes Having Specific Attributes in VBA EXCEL (VBA DOM) XML.

Tags: vba, excel, dom

I need to retrieve only the values from nodes which their attribute are "true". Here's what I have and what I need - appreciate any help:

```
    <AudioTracks>
      <original available="true">ENG</original>
      <localized available="false">SPA</localized>
      <localized available="true">POR</localized>
    </AudioTracks>
```

Here's my code, it will retrieve all values, but I would like to find a way to only retrieve ENG and POR (true). I can't seem to find a suitable way to do it.

```
'AudioTracks
    Set oAudioNodes = featureNode.SelectSingleNode("videos/video/AudioTracks")

    For i = 0 To oAudioNodes.ChildNodes.Length
          sAudio = oAudioNodes.ChildNodes.Item(i).nodeTypedValue & ";" & sAudio
    Next

    sAudio = Left(sAudio, Len(sAudio) - 1)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(intRow, colAudioTracks).Value = NullCheck(sAudio)
    sAudio = ""
    sRawData = ""
```

This will return me ENG;SPA;POR ... But I need it to return only ENG;POR

> Help me Obi Wan, you're my only hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka. I have found a way to make this happen. Not beautiful but works just fine! I just did a small conditional using the getAttribute property. As a parameter, I have just used the attribute name (in this case "available"). Ha! Beautiful - for me.

```
    Set oAudioNodes = featureNode.SelectSingleNode("videos/video/AudioTracks")

    txt = ""

    For i = 0 To oAudioNodes.ChildNodes.Length


          txt = oAudioNodes.ChildNodes.Item(i).getAttribute("available")

If txt = "true" Then sAudio = oAudioNodes.ChildNodes.Item(i).nodeTypedValue & ";" & sAudio

    Next

    sAudio = Left(sAudio, Len(sAudio) - 1)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(intRow, colAudioTracks).Value = NullCheck(sAudio)
    sAudio = ""
    sRawData = ""
    txt = ""
```